# what does "pinned post" mean in Chinese?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

I came across a phrase "pinned post" in this web page - https://purecss.io/layouts/blog/. I tried to find out its corresponding meaning in Chinese, however, I got nothing. I hope someone can explain it for me. Thanks!

Comment: You want to know the equivalent phrase in Chinese (which is off-topic here) or you want a definition in English that you can translate into Chinese?

Comment: I wanna know its meaning in English that I can translate it into Chinese. @KillingTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it’s the same as “置顶文章”, where you keep the post at the  top of your homepage in order for other users to see it. “置顶 “-means stay at the top. “文章”means post. In Chinese social media-weibo微博, it has the same feature to pin your weibo post at the top of your weibopage, which is called “置顶微博”—“weibo at the top”

Comment: It's the answer I want! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Btw, are u from China?

Comment: Apparently I am haaaaaaa! @Collivano Chan